# Point EC2 instance to GoDaddy domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I already have a domain, like exmaple.com and I have a simple app running on an ec2 instance.

I've allocated an elastic IP for this instance, and created a zone on route 53, created `A record`, and also an `alias record`.

I have updated the nameservers from route53 NS records in GoDaddy domain settings(and I should mention that I've waited 48 hours for ns to be propagated, and that part is fine).

When I ping example.com on my own computer, the DNS Name resolve to the correct IP address.
When I check the elastic IP, it's working and shows my website, but when I check example.com it does not show my app and shows `This site can’t be reached`:
[this is a screenshot of what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQBJm.jpg)

I cannot see where's the problem!

Comment: "does not show my app!" - its not very specific? What happens exactly?

Comment: it says: This site can’t be reached. I updated the question and put a screenshot of it too

Comment: If you `curl` the website? `curl -i http://<your-domain-name>`?

Comment: @Marcin Worked: curl -i http://<your-domain-name>
Did not work: curl -i https://<your-domain-name>

Comment: Have you setup HTTPS on your instance? It requires a bit of manual setup to make it work. Its not something that works out-of-the box.

Comment: Oh, no, I have not. so I need to set up it first, right?

Comment: I made answer with general steps for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to using https, rather then http. The http connection works. To **setup https** the following general procedure needs to be undertaken:

1. Get a **public SSL certificate**. Since you are using instance, you can't use AWS ACM for that. In this case a popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ where you can register free SSL certificate for your domain and its subdomains.
2. Setup ssl connectivity on your instance. Often this is done by using **nginx** as a revers proxy. The nginx will provide HTTPS for your instance using the SSL certificates from step 1.
3. Open port **443** (HTTPS) in your **security group**.

The alternative is to front your instance with an application load balancer (ALB). Using it, you can easily get free AWS ACM free certificate and deploy it on the ALB. No actions required on your instance in this case.

Comment: All right got it, I'll try it and will let you know. thank you :)

Comment: @Nasrin No problem. Please let me know how it will go.

Comment: I set up Nginx and also https, and now everything is working. thank you so much :)